# Minimum JDBC driver implementation requirements when connecting to JDBC client

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm in the process of implementing a custom type 3 JDBC driver.   I would like this custom driver to play nice with any compatiable open source JDBC client guis. The typical interfaces (ie, Driver, ResultSet, Connection, Statement,DatabaseMetaData, ResultSetMetaData) to implement are clear, what is confusing is the level of implemenation of these interfaces that is required.  Is there a minimum requirement of implementation so the JDBC driver can sucessfully be recognized by the gui client on connection, on listing the metadata tree (tables/columns), and executing a simple Statement, and displaying a ResultSet? Do I simply noop, throw SQLExceptions, or throw UnSupportedFeature**Exceptions if I don't need it? Will returning nulls in any of these interface methods break a front end client gui? Will the average JDBC gui client be smart enough to recover if I accidentally don't implement something that appeared to be optional?

Thanks,
Amado

Comment: How about reading the specification?

Answer (score 1):

For a definitive answer, you can download and read the latest (version 4.2) JDBC Specification from [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_2-mrel2-spec/index.html).  The specifications for earlier versions can be found by Googling.

In Chapter 6 (in the JSP 4.2 spec), you will find a statement of the "minimum requirement" for implementation of the spec.  (In fact there are two compliance levels.)

If your JDBC driver implementation is not compliant, you can't expect a GUI client (or any other client) to compensate.

Comment: The latest JDBC specification is 4.2, I updated the text and link in your answer. There is a minimum requirement defined in chapter 6 (Compliance), and the API documentation usually also specifies if a method is allowed to throw `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated / simplified my answer.